# What does setting vcov=sandwich result in? I was expecting that it will result in HC consistent standard errors

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, sandwich

However, when I checked the results using, vcovHC=sandwich, I found different results. Can anyone help me to figure out the difference?

```
F1=lm(Rcf~Rmf)
F1test=coeftest(F1,vcov=sandwich)
```

** VS.**

```
F1=lm(Rcf~Rmf)
F1test=coeftest(F1,vcovHC=sandwich)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to obtain sandwich variance estimation with the `coeftest` function. The first works. The second does not. The `...` in sandwich is ignoring the argument named `vcovHC` because it doesn't know what to do with that. You need to tell `coeftest` to use the HC covariance matrix *instead* of the model-based covariance matrix.